# The normalization of the affine algebraic set $V(x^2+y^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I don't have much experience in determining the normalization of an irreducible affine algebraic set. I'm trying this example:
$$F(x,y)=x^2+y^3 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$$
I understand that I need to find a normal algebraic set $\tilde{V}$ and a surjective morphism $\tilde{V}\to V =V(x^2+y^3)$ such that the induced morphism is injective and $\mathbb{C}[\tilde{V}]$  is isomorphic to the integral closure of $\mathbb{C}[V]$.

I know that $\varphi(s)=(s^3,s^2)$ is a normalization, but I don't understand how to get there.

Could you help me, how can I try to resolve it?
What should I do initially?
Any references that can help me?

Comment: $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^3)$ embeds into $\Bbb C(s)$ via $x\mapsto s^3,y\mapsto -s^2$. The image is the subring $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$. Now show that $\Bbb C(s)$ is the fraction field of $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$ and that the integral closure of $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$ in $\Bbb C(s)$ is $\Bbb C[s]$

Comment: what was the argument for thinking about this "$x \mapsto s^3, y \mapsto -s^2 $?

Comment: it's a map that obviously has $(x^2+y^3)$ as its kernel

Comment: Got it, thanks! I will write the answer with the details!

Comment: @LukasHeger One more question: Isn't $ x \mapsto s^3 , y \mapsto s^2$ a normalization?

Comment: That would be the normalization of $V(x^2-y^3)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149384/discussion-between-user-and-lukas-heger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in a discussion in the comments and in chat, but let me just put an answer here to get this off the unanswered queue and to summarize the argument in the proper place.

We can consider the map $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^3) \to \Bbb C[s], x \mapsto s^3, y\mapsto -s^2$. This is a well-defined injective homomorphism (one can check this using the homomorphism theorem). It identifies the coordinate ring $\Bbb C[V]$ with the subring $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3] \subset \Bbb C[s]$. We get an induced homomorphism of fraction fields $\mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]) \to \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb C[s]) = \Bbb C(s)$. Because $s=\frac{s^3}{s^2} \ni \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb C[s^2,s^3])$, we get that this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

$s$ is a root of the monic polynomial $T^2-s^2 \in \Bbb C[s^2,s^3][T]$, implying that $\Bbb C[s]$ is integral over $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$. I claim that $\Bbb C[s]$ is the integral closure of $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$. Note that if $U \in \Bbb C(s)$ is integral over $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$, then it is also integral over $\Bbb C[s]$, because $\Bbb C[s] \supseteq \Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$. But $\Bbb C[s]$ is integrally closed, being a PID. Thus $U \in \Bbb C[s]$, which shows that $\Bbb C[s]$ is indeed the integral closure of $\Bbb C[s^2,s^3]$.

Going back to our original coordinates $x$ and $y$, this proves that the map $\Bbb A^1_\Bbb C \to V(x^2+y^3), s \mapsto (s^3,-s^2)$ is the normalization of $V(x^2+y^3)$.